# Python 3 md5 crack

Tags: python-3.x, md5

I am trying to "convert" a simple python 2 md5 password crack to python 3.  I have tried 2to3 but it does not work as the import md5 does not exist in python 3, instead it uses hashlib.  Not to mention it wanted to change all my "print input("") to eval?  I have looked up the hashlib syntax but i am still at a loss on how to convert the original code to python 3.  Is this possible?

Here is the original code:

```
import md5

counter = 1

pass_in = input("Please enter the MD5 Hash: ")
pwfile = input("Please enter your wordlist file name: ")

try:
    pwfile = open(pwfile, "r")
except:
    print("\nFile Not Found. \nPlease provide a valid path to your wordlist.")
    input("Press Enter to Exit:")
    print("")
    quit()

for password in pwfile:
    filemd5 = md5.new(password.strip()).hexdigest()
    print("Trying password number %d: %s " % (counter, password.strip()))

    counter += 1

    if pass_in == filemd5:
        print("\nMatch Found. \nPassword is: %s" % password)
        break

else:
    print("Password Not Found. \nPlease try another wordlist.")

input("Please press Enter to exit:")
```

Now here is my code:

```
    import hashlib

counter = 1

pass_in = input("Please enter the MD5 Hash: ")
pwfile = input("Please enter your wordlist file name: ")

try:
    pwfile = open(pwfile, "r")
except:
    print("\nFile Not Found. \nPlease provide a valid path to your wordlist.")
    input("Press Enter to Exit:")
    print("")
    quit()

for password in pwfile:
    filemd5 = hashlib.new(password.strip()).hexdigest()
    print("Trying password number %d: %s " % (counter, password.strip()))

    counter += 1

    if pass_in == filemd5:
        print("\nMatch Found. \nPassword is: %s" % password)
        break

else:
    print("Password Not Found. \nPlease try another wordlist.")

input("Please press Enter to exit:")
```

This is the error i keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Hacking/passwordcrack/md5crack.py", line 17, in <module>
    filemd5 = hashlib.new(password.strip()).hexdigest()
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\hashlib.py", line 128, in __hash_new
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)(data)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\hashlib.py", line 95, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type 123456
```

I can tell it doesnt like the hashlib.new line, but im not sure what else to change to make it work?

Noob here and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to call hashlib.md5() if you want to have md5. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Comment: Thanks frlan, but still not working. Maybe i am adding the md5 to the wrong line? 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Hacking/passwordcrack/md5crack.py", line 17, in <module>
    filemd5 = hashlib.md5 .new(password.strip()).hexdigest()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'new''

Comment: What's pwfile content, or the content file?